# Adding help Text to Section of a template

Tags: sitecore-client

I want to add help text to section of the template.
I have added content to all 3 short description, long description and help link.

Templates fields do get all the help text but Template Section is not showing any of the help text.

I understand that the help link functionality might not be supported as click event is bind to expand and collapse of the section. But I am not sure about the other 2 help texts.

Is there any other configuration that we need to enable to get help text on section Header? Or is there any CSS changes that are required.

Images of what is required :

Image of Help Text:
[image]

Now, I need help Text to show up in the section of the item here which is not showing up as of now:
[image]

Comment: Could you please add screenshot with highlighted exact place where you would like to have help text?

Comment: As far as I recall this is not a supported Behavior out of the box.

Comment: @PeterProchazka: Added the images for reference.

Comment: You might be able to do something similar to this to achieve it, it's not available OOTB: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/256/how-do-i-get-my-section-icons-in-the-content-editor-to-show-again

Comment: Thanks for the link @jammykam . I don't want to customize it as the use cases for this are very little. Will keep the link bookmarked in case something like this is required in near future,

Answer (score 2):

It may be a bit late for an answer but it may helps. If you do not want to have custom implementation, you can use the field Display Name.

Navigate to your template and then the section item. Upon clicking on the section item, you will find the field `Display name` under section `Appearance`.

You can add the same name with other details. For example, in your case, it will be Datasource { - your text goes here}. Please see screenshot below:

**Template Section**
[image]

**Result on Sample Item**

[image]

Note that you will still need to reference the name of the item (in my case: Data) if you are targeting that particular section in your code.